# How to combine multiple queries in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I am using solr 4.4.0 and rsolr gem for the corresponding API.

**Background**

- I have a number of taxonomies in my database like rings, earrings, necklaces etc
- I have a number of collections in my database like chunky, modern etc.
- Each taxonomy has a number of sub categories called type

**Input:**
I want to write a query that takes two inputs:
1. Taxonomy
2. Collection

**Desired output:**
I have a set of predefined rules, which give me the taxonomy, collection and type of desired resilts.

Consider the following rule:

```
If Anklets (Chunky)
Then
Necklaces (Chunky) (Beaded)
Earrings (Chunky) (Danglers)
Pendants (Chunky) (With chain)
Bracelets (Chunky) (Beaded)
```

Here the input taxonomy is `anklets` and input collection is `chunky`. And I want 6 results corresponding to each statement inside then condition. So, my result should have 6 beaded necklaces which are under chunky collection. 6 dangler earrings under chunky colelction and so on.....

**The Problem:**
I can specify q and fq and get results for each statement. But I will have to send a separate request corresponding to each statement, making a total of 4 requests. is it possible to form a query so that this can be done in a single request?

Thanks

Comment: how do your separate requests look? Is it not possible to cummulate them using a boolean OR operator?

Comment: @omu_negru : Consider the first statement. `q => "product_taxonomy_name:Necklaces", fq => "+product_collection_value:Chunky, +product_type_value:Beaded", rows => 6`

Comment: @omu_negru: If i combine these with OR like : `fq => "(product_taxonomy_name:Necklaces AND product_collection_value:Chunky AND product_type_value:Beaded) OR (product_taxonomy_name:Earrings AND product_collection_value:Chunky AND product_type_value:Danglers) OR (...) OR (...)". How do I ensure that I get 6 results corresponding to each statement??

Comment: heh....forgot about that part. Now that you mention it, I can't think of an easy way to do it except maybe ask for 100+ results, thus ensuring that you will have 6+ of each, then dump the ones that have lower relevance than the first 6 in each category

Comment: @omu_negru : It can actually be done. Check out the answer. Thanks for your help, you pointed me in the right direction - using AND and OR operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can actually be done using the `group` results feature provided by solr.

1st step is to combine the queries using boolean operators to generate fq:

```
fq => "(product_taxonomy_name:Necklaces AND product_collection_value:Chunky AND product_type_value:Beaded) 
    OR (product_taxonomy_name:Earrings AND product_collection_value:Chunky AND product_type_value:Danglers) 
    OR (...) 
    OR (...)"
```

The pass the following additional parameters in the query:

```
group => true, group.field => product_taxonomy_name, group.limit => 6
```